# Display data based on the value of the key

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have one column(Date) in the table which has some icons and text coming from a dictionary. the table looks like as shown in the below picture. the key 'date' has values of font awesome icon class and normal date string. so i am struggling to get a way to implement date column. here the advantage is i can modify dictionary however i want like i can add, delete or changing the key value pairs to achieve the goal. Thanks in advance.

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7l88wv)

[image: table image]

```js
 data = [
    {
    'date':'fa-refresh',
    'name':"Bengaluru",
    'entities': 14,
    'details':'Lorem Ipsum , Lorem Ipsum',
    'actions':'fa fa-envelope-o',
    'color':'text-primary'
},
{
  'date':'fa-refresh',
  'name':"Hyderabad",
  'entities': 17,
  'details':'Lorem Ipsum,Lorem Ipsum, Ipsum',
  'actions':'fa fa-envelope-o',
  'color':'text-primary'

},
{
  'date':'Nov 4',
  'name':"Mumbai",
  'entities': 20,
  'details':'Lorem Ipsum,Lorem ,Lorem Ipsum',
  'actions':'fa fa-envelope-o,fa fa-share-alt,fa fa-trash-o,fa fa-pencil'

},
{
  'date':'Nov 5',
  'name':"Kerala",
  'entities': 10,
  'details':'Lorem ,Lorem Ipsum,Lorem Ipsum',
  'actions':'fa fa-envelope-o,fa fa-share-alt,fa fa-trash-o,fa fa-pencil'

}
```

```html
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
          <th class="text">Date</th>
          <th class="text">List Name</th>
          <th class="text">No. of Entities</th>
          <th class="text">Actions</th>
          <th class="text"></th>

        </tr>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let items of data | filter: search">
            <td class="text-dark font-weight-bold"> {{items.date}}</td>
            <td  class=" font-weight-bold tablename {{items.color}}">{{ items.name }}</td>
            <td  class="text-dark font-weight-bold">{{ items.entities }}</td>

            <td>
              <span *ngFor="let x of items.actions.split(',')">
                  <i class="{{x}} tableicons"></i>
              </span>
          </td>            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="getdetails(items)">
                Details
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't reuse properties in your model like this. You should keep your date separate from whatever icons you also want to show. You should also use date instances.

**data**

```
data = [
{
  date: null,
  /* other properties omitted for brevity */
},
{
  date: null
},
{
  date: new Date('2019-11-04'),
}
]
```

**html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let items of data | filter: search">
  <td class="text-dark font-weight-bold">
    <span *ngIf="items.date">{{items.date | date:'MMM dd' }}</span>
    <span *ngIf="!items.date"><i class="fas fa-refresh"></i></span>
  </td>
  <!-- other cells omitted for brevity -->
</tr>
```

A simpler model will then let you choose how to display it in the HTML. I have assumed you want to show either a formatted date (read up on how to format dates using the [Angular date pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)), or a font awesome `fas fa-refresh` icon. Obviously change these to suit your needs.

NB The data model I have shown is for a simple case where you either have a date or need to show an icon. If you potentially need to show different icons, then you would need to build that into your model.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your first `td` like,

```
<td class="text-dark font-weight-bold">
    <span *ngIf="items.date.startsWith('fa-')">
       <i [ngClass]="'fa '+items.date"> </i>
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="!items.date.startsWith('fa-')">
       {{items.date}}
    </span>
</td>
```

Conditionally, the `font-awesome-icon` will be rendered if the date key has value starts with `fa-` else the date will be displayed..

> [**Forked stackblitz here ...**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q77rfk)